# assigning values corresponding to keys in ruby hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In my url I have a parameters passed to the rails controllers.
So the params in controller would be

```
params={
  "key1"=>"business", "value1"=>"shoes",
  "key2"=>"date","value2"=>"2014",
  "key3"=>"price", "value3"=>"3000"
}
```

I need to map corresponding keys to the values and store the results in hash.So the output would be

```
{"business"=>"shoes", "date"=>"2014", "price"=>"3000"}
```

How do I do it. Please help.

Comment: Is my answer acceptable, or is there another issue?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more elegant approach, but here's my first shot at it. This assumes you might have the keys/values originally in any order, but specifically named `keyN` and `valueN`.

```
params={
  "key1"=>"business", "value1"=>"shoes",
  "key2"=>"date","value2"=>"2014",
  "key3"=>"price", "value3"=>"3000"
}

keys = Array.new
values = Array.new

params.each do |k,v|
  m = k.match(/(key|value)(\d+)/)
  eval("#{m[1]}s[#{m[2]}] = '#{v}'") if m
end

hash_values = Hash[keys.zip(values)].delete_if { |k| k.nil? }
# => {"business"=>"shoes", "date"=>"2014", "price"=>"3000"}
```